# Missing values in prediction

Tags: r, statistics, prediction, missing-data, imputation

I have a simple linear regression with missing values in the training set. I found many nice imputation methods to estimate a good model for this situation.

What I could not find is how to predict a new point with the model when this point can have missing values as well. Is there a common way?

Comment: Some people use imputation to fill in the missing values. You used it in the training, why not the prediction? look up "hot deck imputation" or "stratified imputation" for two simple methods.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, lmo! I looked them up and see that for simple methods (on Wikipedia they call them "single imputation") it is indeed possible. Do you know if there is also a way for multiple imputation as this seems to be the state of the art?

Comment: My understanding is that if you are simply interested in prediction, and not estimation of standard errors / inference, then these types of methods should be sufficient. However, there are the packages mice and mi (I think) and probably others. You can find more on CRAN Taskviews. Here's the [social sciences page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SocialSciences.html), which lists more.

Comment: Thanks again.That makes sense! About the packages: I tried some before including `Amelia`, `mice` and `missForest` and found nothing about prediction with missing values. They seem to finish with the fitted model.